# When does Dart implicitly typecast?

Tags: dart, casting, type-inference

I'm trying to understand implicit typecasting in Dart. I'm coming from a background in Typescript and Kotlin. I would have expected all but `Predator1` in the following to properly interpret `food` as an `Animal`. The only reason I'd make an exception for `Predator1` is because `assert()` doesn't run in production. I don't understand why type inference isn't working in the other cases.

```dart
class Organism {}

class Animal extends Organism {
  void eat(Organism food) {}
  void kill() {}
}

class Predator1 extends Animal {
  void eat(Organism food) {
    assert(food is Animal, "Food must be an animal");
    food.kill(); // error: kill not defined
  }
}

class Predator2 extends Animal {
  void eat(Organism food) {
    if (food is! Animal) throw ArgumentError("Food must be an animal");
    food.kill(); // error: kill not defined
  }
}

class Predator3 extends Animal {
  void eat(Organism food) {
    if (food is! Animal) {
      throw ArgumentError("Food must be an animal");
    } else {
      food.kill(); // error: kill not defined
    }
  }
}

class Predator4 extends Animal {
  void eat(Organism food) {
    if (food is Animal) {
      food.kill(); // compiles fine, but sheesh!
    } else {
      throw ArgumentError("Food must be an animal");
    }
  }
}

class Predator5 extends Animal {
  void eat(Organism food) {
    var prey = food as Animal; // compiles fine, but not ideal exception
    prey.kill(); // compiles fine
  }
}
```

Is this expected behavior? Is there any way for me to throw a meaningful exception without logically unnecessary code? What cases am I missing?

(This is my third time thinking that I've obviously found an oversight in Dart, and yet each of the prior two times I learned Dart was operating as intended. So I'll keep asking basic questions here instead of reporting problems as I slowly make sense of this language.)

Answer (score 1):

[No type promotion currently occurs for `is!`](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/80).

Similarly, [type inference currently does not consider `assert`s either](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36883).

Comment: Thank you for locating these language issues!